# C# cancel a long running task that not a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am new to c# task, what I want to do is convert

```
downloadThread = new Thread(DownLoadFile); 
downloadThread.Start();
```

to task like

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(DownLoadFile);
```

I also know to use CancellationTokenSource to cancel the task. However, the examples I saw are all long loop running threads, such as `for`, `foreach`, `while`, and they check `IsCancellationRequested` to cancel the task in the loop.

```
if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    break;
}
```

But my long running task is to download a file with FTP. The `GetFile` method is from a third party dll library.

```
ftp.GetFile(ftpPath, dest, false);
```

Since my long running task is not in any loops, how can I check for and then cancel it?

Comment: You could use a while, f.e. while(ftp.GetFile) , make a check. If the check is OK, do a wait afterwards.

Comment: I assume you are not interested in simple Task.Abort()?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the third party API doesn't support cancellation, there's no clean way of doing it. You *can* [abort the thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx), but I'd *strongly* advise that you only do that if you're killing the whole process (or at least the AppDomain).

If at all possible, find an equivalent API which *does* support cancellation, or just abandon the request and let it take its course, just ignoring the result.

Comment: Even `Thread.Abort` only works if you're executing managed code, right? This may require something even more prejudicial.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: thanks, seems no simple way. I will implement my own ftp download method using build-in ftp class, and check and cancel in read stream while