# Deliberately aborting a Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

Assuming I have a very long running operation that does not contain any loop, I mean the nature of the operation is long running without any recursion and repetition. In this case if I use the `CancellationToken` type to throw a cancelling exception or a `Boolean` Flag for "Safely" cancelling the task, the token or flag can never be reached.

Now the only goal would be to break the running task regardless of whether aborting is a good or bad approach. When using threads, the abort method is present (I'm not interested in discussing about it's disadvantages as I'm already aware of it), but when it comes to the Task type, I don't see it there. And assuming my Task has to return a value, then threads are out of questions.

What is the safest and most efficient way to implement this.

Comment: There is no abort method because tasks are not necessarily tied to threads.

Comment: @dcastro: I already know that, I'm looking for the solution. I wanna break it no matter what, very much like Environment.Exit(0) that breaks all running operations and close the application.

Comment: what is the context here ?

Comment: A bit harsh solution: Creating the `Task` in an other `AppDomain` and dispose that `AppDomain` if you have to kill the task? ^^;

Comment: You want to abort task from from inside executing of task or from outside?

Comment: @Some1Pr0: That is a very very unsafe approach. It can raise errors

Comment: Capture the thread (Thread.CurrentThread) inside the task when it starts  and put it in a variable accessible outside the task. Just note that Tasks normally run on the treadpool. Don't know what happens when you abort thread pool threads.

Comment: @PleaseTeach: I'm not using threads, I'm using a Task.

Comment: @Arrrr This should prove interesting for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359910/is-it-possible-to-abort-a-task-like-aborting-a-thread-thread-abort-method

Comment: @Arrrr: I am aware of that and was partially kidding but I don't think there is an elegant way to do it if the Task is constantly working and the Cancelation is never reached, I would really like to see a good answer for this one...

Comment: @PaulZahra: I'm taking about Task type not Thread type

Comment: @Arrrr we all know you are tasking about tasks not threads... there is no way to abort a task, they run in a thread.. you need to kill the process or abort the main thread somehow

Comment: @PleaseTeach: What is the point of running the Task in the thread? In that case I would implement a new Threaded-Type. I said I'm not interested in thread. We all know that thread can be aborted easily.

Comment: @Arrrr Try reading the linked SO post and read the post directly under the accepted answer.

Comment: @PaulZahra: It was useless.

Comment: Basically you need to build support for cancellation in your BeginStart, you haven't so you can only do it by aborting the thread or appdomain... Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390599/c-sharp-cancel-a-long-running-task-that-not-a-loop

Comment: @PaulZahra: Actually that is not possible

Comment: @Arrrr 3rd party? Then your stuck with thread / app domain abortion... euch.

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify how the duplicate doesn't apply to your question, but please do so constructively.

Answer (score -1):

You can kill the process,

```
process.Kill();
```

Cancellation task or aborting task is never promised regardless of what documentation says.

**OR**

You can start your tasks in a thread and then use `thread.abort();`.

I am afraid you don't have much choice available here.To be more sure, you need to provide context.

[image]

Comment: I already mentioned it is of no use

Comment: You didn't read text of question carefully

Comment: updated it now.. User edited his question after i answered like in a seconds

Comment: Please refer to this line of my question. `And assuming my Task has to return a value, then threads are out of questions. `

Comment: @Arrrr provide the complete context, I would be able to provide you a better answer then